# Reversing Words of String

Tags: c#, string, reverse, words

I have the following code for `Reversing string`:

```
static public string rever(string s)
{
string temp = "";
int i;
int j = 0;
  for (i = (s.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
  {
  temp += s[i];
  j++;
  }

return temp;
}
```

Currently it reverses the String, I want it to be able to reverse order of words in string, for example

```
input string "I am good"

Output: "good am I"
```

All I want to do now is `Reverse` the order of `Words` in my string. According to my research, It can be done in two passes, but I dont know how to achieve it. Like how can I alter it to work for Reversing Words as well?

**NOTE: I want to do this without using any built-in library functions**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about two passes.  But it's very simple algorithm.

```
string s="I am good", temp="";
int i=s.length-1, t=0;
while(true){
 if(i<0)
  break;
 if(s[i]!=' '){
  i--;
  t++;
 }
 else{
  for(int i2=0;i2<t;i2++)
   temp+=s[i+i2+1];
  temp+=" ";
  t=0;
  i--;
 }
 if(i==-1&&t!=0){
  for(int i2=0;i2<t;i2++)
   temp+=s[i+i2+1];
  break;
 }
}
```